# Prevent gulp-htmllint from skipping invalid html files

Tags: html, gulp, htmllint

I'm using [gulp-htmllint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmllint) to check files with html fragments. However, to my surprise, it *skips* files with invalid markup. I'd love to get "as good as possible" linting, but at the very least **I want it to fail / report an error on invalid html**.

Here's a repro. First the `gulpfile.js` (requires appropriate `npm install` commands beforehand):

```js
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    htmllint = require("gulp-htmllint"), 
    path = require('path');

gulp.task("default", [], function() {
    return gulp.src("src/*.html")
        .pipe(htmllint({}, reporter));
});

function reporter(filepath, issues) {
    var filename = path.basename(filepath);
    if (issues.length > 0) {
        issues.forEach(function (issue) {
            gutil.log(gutil.colors.cyan('[lintHtml] ') + gutil.colors.white(filename + ' [' + issue.line + ',' + issue.column + ']: ') + gutil.colors.red('(' + issue.code + ') ' + issue.msg));
        });
        process.exitCode = 1;
    }
}
```

The `reporter` is based off the example on the package's home page.

With this `src/fragment.html` file:

```html
<span style="color: red;">Test 1.</span>
<span style="color: green;">Test 2.</span>
```

I'll nicely get:

> ```
> [08:04:06] Using gulpfile ~\myapp\gulpfile.js
> [08:04:06] Starting 'default'...
> [08:04:06] [lintHtml] fragment.html [1,6]: (E001) the `style` attribute is banned
> [08:04:06] [lintHtml] fragment.html [2,6]: (E001) the `style` attribute is banned
> [08:04:06] Finished 'default' after 38 ms
> ```

But, if I make the html file invalid like so:

```html
<span style="color: red;"Test 1.</span>
<span style="color: green;">Test 2.</span>
```

I get:

> ```
> [08:05:06] Using gulpfile ~\myapp\gulpfile.js
> [08:05:06] Starting 'default'...
> [08:05:06] Finished 'default' after 25 ms
> ```

As if there's nothing wrong.

How do I get the process to report errors and fail when my fragment has such a problem?

PS. I ended up [cross-posting to Github as an issue too](https://github.com/yvanavermaet/gulp-htmllint/issues/6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do this without changes to gulp-htmllint itself. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/yvanavermaet/gulp-htmllint/blob/master/src/index.js#L60) you see that it only provides a success handler to the htmllint promise:

```
lint.then(function(issues) {
    issues.forEach(function(issue) {
        issue.msg = issue.msg || htmllint.messages.renderIssue(issue);
    });
    reporter(file.path, issues);
});
```

To output cases where the linting process fails because of invalid html, it would have to provide a reject handler as well:

```
lint.then(function(issues) {
    issues.forEach(function(issue) {
        issue.msg = issue.msg || htmllint.messages.renderIssue(issue);
    });
    reporter(file.path, issues);
}).catch(function(error) {
    //do something useful here
    console.log(file.path + ': ' + error.toString());
});
```

That means you have two options:

- Fork the project on github and implement this yourself
- Find another gulp plugin that does this (maybe [gulp-htmlhint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlhint) or [gulp-html5-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html5-lint)?)

Comment: Again, a great reminder to check the *source* of open source, when I want to know if it supports something. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment (and the solution :-)). I've implemented this and released version 0.0.7 of gulp-htmllint.